# Nested foreach loop in laravel 5.2

Tags: sql, foreach, nested, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables

1 Advertiser

2 Adverts

- id

Advertiser can have multiple adverts

[image]

3 instances

- id
- ad_id
- date

[image]

Adverts can have multiple date - date is the column in instances table

```
 $input = Input::get('fullname'); // fullname is the id of adverstiser
 // input is the advertiser id
   $adverts = DB::table('adverts')->where('a_id',$input)->get();
return view('adverts.index', compact( 'adverts'));
```

This query will give me all adverts data related to advertiser.

fine with that.

in my adverts.index

```
 @foreach($adverts as $advert)
 <div class="caption">
     <ul>           
          <li><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> {{$advert->height}}x{{$advert->height}}</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-file"></i> {{$advert->finfo}}</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Last seen:</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-link"></i> {{$advert->domain}}</li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <a href="{{$advert->src}}" target="_blank">Visit full ad</a></li>              
      </ul>

  </div>
  @endforeach
```

I would like to get the last seen date from the instance table.

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS "Last seen date" FROM instances WHERE ad_id =1
```

ad_id is the primary key id from adverts table

I would like to pass the value of this query to them same view as above 
adverts.index

Is the loop must be done in view?

Or something else I am missing.

Comment: So from what I understand, each `$advert` should have its own "last seen date"?  Also, do you have [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) defined for these tables?

Comment: Each adverts has multiple dates, but wants to pick up the last seen dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first see if you can get the maximum date for each `advert` that has at least one corresponding `instance`.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
$instances = DB::table('instances')
    ->select(DB::raw('*, MAX(date) as last_seen_date'))
    ->groupBy('ad_id')
    ->get();
```

**If you can get this to work first**, then you can join it with your `advertiser` and `adverts` tables to match a particular advertiser and get the remaining information for each advert.  You can also do a `leftJoin` to ensure that you grab all `adverts`, even ones that don't have any matching `instances`.

I would also strongly encourage you to [define models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), which will make it easier to create reusable query fragments ("scopes") throughout your application.